# Google Drive API permission propagation and the File userPermission property

Tags: google-drive-api

I am not sure if I am experiencing bugs or if I am doing something wrong. I am developing an app that allows users to create and share a folder on their Google Drive so they can collaborate on the contents of the folder. The folder is created at the root of the user's Google Drive and initially contains a couple of files and one sub-folder with more files.

The first issue is that after inserting a new permission on the main folder, the permission will usually propagate down to all the files and sub-folders, but sometimes it fails to insert the permission on one of the files in the sub directory. Is this feature of propagating permissions to sub-directories something that is officially supported or am i suppose to insert a permission into all the files separately?

The second issue I am experiencing involves the use of the File's userPermission property to check if the role of the current user has changed. It seems that the userPermission property sometimes contains the permission of a recent user and not the current user. The feature I am trying to implement is the ability for a user with whom a folder was shared to check periodically if their permission role has changed. For example has the users permission role changed from "reader" to "writer" or vice-versa. This usually works by listing the folder with the fileId and checking the role property of the userPermission property of the file. However if I am testing this feature with both the user who shares and the user with whom it is shared working within the same client, the get file result will often list the userPermission as the last one to access the file and not the current user. I have tested if this was because I was using the wrong oauth information in the request header but I have ruled this possibility out, the oauth headers are correct for each separate call to get file. I added a test call to about witch lists the users permissionId, just before a call to get file to confirm who the authorized user is. Sill the userPermission with the "me" name appears for the wrong user.

The workaround I have found is to use list files which returns the file in the list with the correct userPermission.

In the reference located at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource for the description of the userPermission property is "The permissions for the authenticated user on this file."

I am wrong to interpret this to mean the userPermission will always show the role of the current user? And if it is showing the wrong permission, what could be the cause??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the first problem, which was that after sharing a folder, only one of its contents would consistently not get shared, I have discovered the cause. The file that was not getting shared is actually a Fusion Tables file and in my script, immediately after inserting the permission, a call is made to insert a new row into the Fusion table file which seems to prevent the permission from being added to that file at that time, or ever. So the workaround I found is to wait a couple of seconds after making the insert permission call, then check that the permission is already in place using a list permission call before calling the Fusion Tables query.

Now with regard to the second problem, this is probably a bug of some sort since I confirmed that I am using the correct oauth token, and by the fact that the workaround I have found works, which is to use a call to list file instead of get file. The only difference is that the file name or other query parameter is required to make the call in addition to the file id. In my case the file object returned with the list file will always contain the correct values in the userPermission field whereas with get file, the userPermission will sometimes contain information for an other user.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue with file share permission. I'm sharing google drive files with other google account user using Google Drive API. Sometimes my file is sharing with other google user email_id but sometimes its not sharing. Is there configuration I need to do for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`userPermission` and `me` represents the current authenticated user, if it's showing the wrong permission you're authenticating the user with the wrong token.

> the permission will usually propagate down to all the files and sub-folders

This case may not be true for sub folders and files with their own explicit permissions.